# shouldn't it generate infinite looping?

Tags: javascript, node.js

according to this website:

"https://medium.com/man-moon/express-js-under-the-hood-6452c897b316"

this snippet of code refers to what const app = express() is executed:

```
module.exports = function createApplication() {
    var app = function(req, res, next) {
        app.handle(req, res, next);
    };
    mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
    mixin(app, proto, false);
    app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
    app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
    app.init();
    return app;
}
```

"

how the following is possible:

```
"var app = function(req, res, next) {
        app.handle(req, res, next);
    };"
```

we have app receving the function which within its scope there is a reference to app as well
shouldn't that genereta an infinite looping?? the way I see app is pointing to sabe reference right?

Comment: Why should that generate any kind of loop? All you do is reference the variable that you defined

Comment: There's no looping execution, `app` doesn't *call* itself. It only *references* itself.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm a little confused isn't the outter app overwrite the inner app reference?
when i write some similar code then the outer and inner app variable are the same reference

Comment: @Eulereulerhenriuqe What do you mean by "overwrite"? There's no assignment anywhere. Yes, they are the same reference. So what?

Comment: It's `app.handle(..`  Not `app(..`  so no recursion..

Answer (score 1):

There is no infinite loop here.  Let's just dissect what each line of this does.  Here's the code with line numbers added:

```
1 module.exports = function createApplication() {
2    var app = function(req, res, next) {
3        app.handle(req, res, next);
4    };
5    mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
6    mixin(app, proto, false);
7    app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
8    app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
9    app.init();
10   return app;
```

Line 1 creates the function that will be used in `const app = express()`.

Line 2 defines a local function named `app`.  Inside the body of that function is a call to `app.handle()`.  More on that later.

Lines 5 and 6 add a bunch of methods from other classes to the `app` object (allowing it to be a combination of methods from other classes known as a "mixin").

Lines 7 and 8 define parts of a default implementation for the `req` and `res` objects that will be used in handling requests.  This is kind of used like a "prototype", though it isn't a classic system prototype.

Line 9 calls the Express object initialization code that further initializes the object.  You can see that code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/8368dc178af16b91b576c4c1d135f701a0007e5d/lib/application.js#L64) and it is what you would normally find in a constructor.

```
app.init = function init() {
  this.cache = {};
  this.engines = {};
  this.settings = {};

  this.defaultConfiguration();
};
```

Line 10 returns this new object that was just created.

So, in understanding what is actually executing here, you can see that the call to `app.handle()` is not actually executed when `createApplication()` is called.  Instead, it's executed some time later when `app(req, res, next)` gets called.  And, `app.handle()` is one of those methods that was added to the `app` object in this line `mixin(app, proto, false);`.

So, when `createApplication()` is called, it just creates the `app` variable, assigns a bunch of things to it as properties, does some other initialization and then returns that new function object.  It does not call that new function object at that time and thus `app.handle(...)` is not executed when `createApplication()` is called.

Sometime later when Express is processing a request, `app(req, res, next)` will get called and that will then cause it to call `app.handle(req, res, next)`.  But, that doesn't create any sort of loop.

The code for `app.handle()` is where Express routing (to match a pre-defined route with the current incoming request) starts and is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/8368dc178af16b91b576c4c1d135f701a0007e5d/lib/application.js#L165).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and works if you also define `app.handle`, for example:

```js
var app = function(a) {
  app.handle(a);
};
app.handle = console.log;
app(1);
```

`app` is a function and `app.handle` is another function. The console displays it as

```
[Function: app] { handle: [Function: log] }
```

When you run this code, the argument 1 is logged to the console, because that's what `app.handle` does.

Comment: what happens therer? I mean app.handle = console.log; is set afterwards the calling of it within var app = function(a) I thought javascript line order mattered

Comment: You should debug the code. `app.handle` is called only when `app(1)` is executed, which happens after the `app.handle` assignment.

Comment: man you're so right!

Comment: just one more thing. So the app.handle is being defined elsewhere other than the code snippet I've posted right? in the express example?

Comment: Yes, in the line `mixin(app, proto, false);`

Comment: I don't see any mention of "handle" in this line. Are you saying the proto is handle?

Comment: I1m following what you've previously said in "It is possible and works if you also define app.handle"

Comment: `proto` is https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js

Comment: just don't get it :(